# How to use TextBox.Watermark in Silverlight 4?

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0

While browsing MSDN documentation, you may come across this gem: TextBox.Watermark.

"Awesome! I've been wanting a built-in way to do watermarking on my text boxes! This is great, let me go ahead and set that in XAML!"

```
<TextBox Watermark="This is my watermark" Margin="20"></TextBox>
```

Unfortunately, if you run this you won’t get what you expect:

[image]

And the detail:
[image]

What is this? Well, look at the MSDN documentation closely:
[image]

That's right. It's supported in Silverlight 4, but it also says "Do not use in a Silverlight 4 application". If you do use it, you receive a System.NotImplemented exception. To verify, here is the code for the property decompiled via Reflector:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public object Watermark
{
get
{
StubHelper.ThrowIfNotInDesignMode();
return base.GetValue(WatermarkProperty);
}
set
{
StubHelper.ThrowIfNotInDesignMode();
base.SetValue(WatermarkProperty, value);
}
}
```

There it is – it throws an exception any time it's not in design mode. This makes no sense right? Why would Microsoft do this?

Unfortunately I haven't found any definitive answer yet, however if I had to guess it's because Microsoft is planning on implementing a Watermark behavior on the TextBox control in a future version (perhaps v5) and wanted to effectively reserve this property so third party control creators don't subclass TextBox and create their own Watermark property. 
I know of at least one control vendor, ComponentOne, who has a control that inherits from TextBox and provides a Watermark property. 
To me, it seems this is Microsoft's way of discouraging people from using this property name on their own TextBox subclasses.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create One Class library project . Add Class File  use the Following code .....After that Add The In this dll In Your Project.

```
public class WatermarkTextBox : TextBox 
{ 
    private bool displayWatermark = true; 
    private bool hasFocus = false; 
     public WatermarkTextBox() 
    { 
        this.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(WatermarkTextBox_GotFocus); 
        this.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(WatermarkTextBox_LostFocus); 
        this.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(WatermarkTextBox_TextChanged); 
        this.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(WatermarkTextBox_Unloaded); 
    } 

    private void WatermarkTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (!hasFocus && Text == "") 
        { 
            setMode(true); 
            displayWatermark = true; 
            this.Text = Watermark; 
        } 
    } 

    private void WatermarkTextBox_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        this.GotFocus -= WatermarkTextBox_GotFocus; 
        this.LostFocus -= WatermarkTextBox_LostFocus; 
        this.Unloaded -= WatermarkTextBox_Unloaded; 
        this.TextChanged -= WatermarkTextBox_TextChanged; 
    } 

    private void WatermarkTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        hasFocus = true; 
        if (displayWatermark) 
        { 
            setMode(false); 
            this.Text = ""; 
        } 
    } 
    private void WatermarkTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        hasFocus = false; 
        if (this.Text == "") 
        { 
            displayWatermark = true; 
            setMode(true); 
            this.Text = Watermark; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            displayWatermark = false; 
        } 
    } 
    private void setMode(bool watermarkStyle) 
    { 
        if (watermarkStyle) 
        { 
            this.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic; 
            this.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            this.FontStyle = FontStyles.Normal; 
            this.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black); 
        } 
    } 
    public new string Watermark 
    { 
        get { return GetValue(WatermarkProperty) as string; } 
        set { SetValue(WatermarkProperty, value); } 
    } 
    public static new readonly DependencyProperty WatermarkProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Watermark", typeof(string), typeof(WatermarkTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(watermarkPropertyChanged)); 
    private static void watermarkPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        WatermarkTextBox textBox = obj as WatermarkTextBox; 
        if (textBox.displayWatermark) 
        { 
            textBox.Text = e.NewValue.ToString(); 
            textBox.setMode(true); 
        } 
    }
```

XAML:

```
  xmlns:watertext="clr-namespace:SilverlightClassLibrary1;assembly=SilverlightClassLibrary1"


    <watertext:WatermarkTextBox Watermark="WElcome" Margin="150,115,120,166"></watertext:WatermarkTextBox>
```

Comment: +1 for very nice solution. Works fine in Silverlight 5 by the way. Interesting to note that SL5 MSDN documentation still has the same conflicting information about the Watermark property.

Comment: Note also that I tweaked the code slightly, mainly to address design-time error if Watermark property is not set. Updated code added as new answer below.

Comment: You have registered to events in constructor , but in unload you are unregistered from them (which is fine), but this brings to problems with tab control, Tab control will unload its content and load when  appropriate tab is pressed, so maybe you should register to events in Loaded event instead of constructor.

Answer (score 3):

I revised @mani kandan's solution slightly to fix design-time error if Watermark property is not set.  Also added a HasValue boolean property to be able to easily check whether user has entered text in the TextBox, and lastly changed to treat all-whitespace entries as non-entries (i.e., continue to display watermark).

Revised code:

```
public class WatermarkTextBox : TextBox
{

    private bool displayWatermark = true;
    private bool hasFocus = false;

    public WatermarkTextBox()
    {
        this.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(WatermarkTextBox_GotFocus);
        this.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(WatermarkTextBox_LostFocus);
        this.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(WatermarkTextBox_TextChanged);
        this.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(WatermarkTextBox_Unloaded);
    }

    private void WatermarkTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!hasFocus && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Text))
        {
            setMode(true);
            displayWatermark = true;
            // avoid design-time error if Watermark not specified
            this.Text = (Watermark == null ? string.Empty : Watermark);
        }
    }

    private void WatermarkTextBox_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.GotFocus -= WatermarkTextBox_GotFocus;
        this.LostFocus -= WatermarkTextBox_LostFocus;
        this.Unloaded -= WatermarkTextBox_Unloaded;
        this.TextChanged -= WatermarkTextBox_TextChanged;
    }

    private void WatermarkTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        hasFocus = true;
        if (displayWatermark)
        {
            setMode(false);
            this.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void WatermarkTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        hasFocus = false;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Text))
        {
            displayWatermark = true;
            setMode(true);
            this.Text = (Watermark == null ? string.Empty : Watermark);
        }
        else
        {
            displayWatermark = false;
        }
    }

    private void setMode(bool watermarkStyle)
    {
        if (watermarkStyle)
        {
            this.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
            this.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        }
        else
        {
            this.FontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
            this.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        }
    }

    public new string Watermark
    {
        get { return GetValue(WatermarkProperty) as string; }
        set { SetValue(WatermarkProperty, value); }
    }

    public static new readonly DependencyProperty WatermarkProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Watermark", typeof(string), typeof(WatermarkTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(watermarkPropertyChanged));
    private static void watermarkPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WatermarkTextBox textBox = obj as WatermarkTextBox;
        if (textBox.displayWatermark)
        {
            textBox.Text =  e.NewValue.ToString();
            textBox.setMode(true);
        }
    }

    public bool HasValue
    {
        get 
        {
            // if watermark has been specified, then compare to text value to determine if text set by user,
            // otherwise check to see if empty or whitespace.
            if (this.Watermark != null)
                return this.Watermark != this.Text;
            else
                return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Text);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out this one based on behaviours

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class WatermarkBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
    {
        public String Watermark
        {
            get { return this.GetValue(WatermarkProperty) as String; }
            set { this.SetValue(WatermarkProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty WatermarkProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Watermark", typeof(String), typeof(WatermarkBehavior), new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnWatermarkChanged)));

        private static void OnWatermarkChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var behavior = d as WatermarkBehavior;
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewValue as String))
            {
                behavior.SetWatermarkIfNeeded();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            this.AssociatedObject.GotFocus += GotFocus;
            this.AssociatedObject.LostFocus += LostFocus;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            this.AssociatedObject.GotFocus -= GotFocus;
            this.AssociatedObject.LostFocus -= LostFocus;
        }

        private void GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.AssociatedObject.Text == this.Watermark)
            {
                this.AssociatedObject.Text = String.Empty;
                this.AssociatedObject.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            }
        }

        private void LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetWatermarkIfNeeded();
        }

        private void SetWatermarkIfNeeded()
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.AssociatedObject.Text))
            {
                this.SetWatermark();
            }
        }

        private void SetWatermark()
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.Text = this.Watermark;
            this.AssociatedObject.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="GreenField.Targeting.Controls.BasketTargets.EditorView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
  xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
  mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <local:WatermarkBehavior Watermark="{Binding Watermark}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
  </TextBox>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use it successfully in Silverlight 5

Try out this link :
[TextBox.Watermark](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/10/22/silverlight-watermark-text-box-control.aspx)

I am successfully using the WatermarkTextBox in a Silverlight 5 MVVM application.

Answer (score 2):

Create One Class library project . Add Class File use the Following code

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Project.Controls
{
    public class WatermarkEditBox : TextBox
    {

        TextBlock lbl = new TextBlock()
        {
            IsHitTestVisible = false,
            Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray),
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
            Margin = new Thickness(3,0,0,0)
        };
        public string WatermarkText { get { return lbl.Text; } set { lbl.Text = value; } }

        public WatermarkEditBox()
        {
            this.Loaded += WatermarkEditBox_Loaded;
        }

        void WatermarkEditBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.UpdateLayout();
            Grid g = GetObjectOfType<Grid>(this, "RootElement");
            if (g != null)
            {
                g.Children.Add(lbl);
            }
            this.TextChanged += WatermarkEditBox_TextChanged;
        }

        void WatermarkEditBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Text.Length == 0)
                lbl.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            else
                lbl.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public TObject GetObjectOfType<TObject>(DependencyObject parent, string name) where TObject : DependencyObject
        {
            int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                if (child is TObject && child.GetValue(NameProperty).ToString() == name)
                {
                    return child as TObject;
                }
                else
                {
                    TObject obj = GetObjectOfType<TObject>(child, name);
                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        return obj;
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

XAML:

```
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Project.Controls"

<Controls:WatermarkEditBox WatermarkText="фильтр" Width="100"/>
```