# Textbox null text

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm looking to have a grayed out info text inside the textbox, to avoid needing a label for everything.

Something like this:
[image]

In WPF i would play around with triggers and such, but in Silverlight i'm not exactly sure how it should be done. Is there an existing control like this somewhere for silverlight?

Here would be a link to one done with WPF and triggers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7433840/184746

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992984/how-to-use-textbox-watermark-in-silverlight-4